# Android non whitelisted headers are filtered out by CustomChromeTab

Tags: android, kotlin, google-chrome

I am using CustomChromeTab in my application, now there is a requirement that we need to send the an additional headers "access_token" to it. I am following the suggested guidelined here https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/custom-tabs/headers/#set_up_a_custom_tabs_connection_to_validate_the_asset_link.

But when I am inspecting my headers using (chrome://inspect) I can't see any token entry in the headers. Below is the code I am using for this.

In My activity I am adding the headers like this:

```
  val intent = CustomTabsIntent.Builder(session).build()
        // Example non-cors-whitelisted headers.
        val headers = Bundle()
        headers.putString("bearer-token", "Some token");
        intent.intent.putExtra(Browser.EXTRA_HEADERS, headers)
       intent.launchUrl(this@MainActivity, URL)
```

I have also created a assetlink.json file which we are hositng on our company domain https://mydomain/.well-known/assetlinks.json. Content of the file is

```
 [{
    "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
    "target": {
        "namespace": "android_app",
        "package_name": "com.example.myapplication",
        "sha256_cert_fingerprints": ["96:FB:37:03:7D:D2:EA:30:50:65:79:05:BE:17:18:84:68:AB:40:E3:74:6C:AC:F0:36:93:85:B2:0A:94:2A:A8"]
    }
}]
```

I have linked the reference of this json file in my android app manifest file

```
<string name="asset_statements">[{
      \"include\": \"https://mydomain/.well-known/assetlinks.json\"
    }]</string>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

My manifest.xml file looks like this

```
       <meta-data
            android:name="asset_statements"
            android:resource="@string/asset_statements" />
```